# Prevent from going to sleep in a KVM usage

Tags: mac, sleep-wake, kvm

To help in context, I'm using a Windows Computer and an Air M2 Mac.
They are both connected to a KVM which switches between computers while keeping my devices (KB, mouse, and dual monitor). My Mac's lid is closed when I'm working on this setup.

If I have something to do on my PC, I switch the KVM to PC then back to my Mac. Then, I have to open the lid of the Mac to get to power on; then I close it again.

**How can I prevent my Mac going into sleep when switching between computers?**

I tried `caffeinate -i -s` and I tried changing settings in lockscreen.

Comment: Do you have the power adapter plugged into the Mac?  What settings did you change in the lockscreen?

Comment: Power adapter is plugged in, my current settings were "Never" for every setting, to try if it was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The key to your answer is the utility [`pmset`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) which allows you to set various power management settings.

`pmset -g cap` will list the settings supported by your hardware and `pmset -g live` will give you the settings currently in use. `pmset -g assertions` will give you the current status of assertions (which is what `caffeinate` raises to do its job).

If you have a careful read of the [man page](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) you can figure out how to stop your computer from going to sleep (`pmset sleep 0` will probably do the job but please read the man page). You might also want to write a script to reverse the settings for when you leave the computer and *want* it to go to sleep.