# how do I make macOS never make a MacBook inactive?

Tags: power, power-management

I would like to make sure that my macOS MacBook is always running, even when the MacBook cover is closed (though connected to the power). There is a program running on the MacBook that needs to be continuously running and have access to the Internet.

However, it seems that every so often the MacBook loses its connection to the Internet, and then I have to open the MacBook, hit something on the keyboard, and it is back to action as before.

From reading on it online, I have to switch the low power mode to off (as I did, see below), but it has continued to happen even when I did that. Is there another switch anywhere that I need to toggle to make it work? (The MacBook has always been connected to the power.)

[image]

EDIT: I should mention that the laptop, together with another one, is on a KVM switch, and I believe it happens only when the laptop is not the one selected in the KVM switched.

Comment: See the link in this question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/453683/119271

Comment: sorry, I am not sure why this tutorial is relevant, my laptop is always connected to a power adaptor (though the keyboard and mouse are on KVM switch, what I meant is that it sometimes happens when I switch away with the keyboard/mouse). It was good to learn it is called clamshell mode...

Comment: The commands in the *question* are meant to disable sleep and hibernation.  But now that you mention KVM, the issue is going to be the KVM likely disconnects the video (high end KVMs keep the video active) and will eventually put the laptop to sleep.  To be in closed clamshell, a keyboard, mouse, monitor and power are required.

Comment: See this question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/453807/119271

Comment: @Allan thanks, it sounds like pmset is indeed somehow the way to go...